# obj c > php > mysql authentication... so close!

Tags: php, mysql, objective-c, authentication, if-statement

I know there are quite a few threads similar to this but I just can't put my finger on what im doing wrong on my code, I am able to get entries into mysql via the iphone simulator, so it is working, but i can't fix the alert priorities and the } else if {'s...

basically its a 4 string registration page, sends the 4 strings of data to my .php file, my php file slots the info into my database. Couple problems:

1. If there is nothing in any of the 4 fields, and the user clicks the create button, it does give the "missing fields" alert appropriately, however it sends a blank entry to my database, so it's obviously not listening to me when i try tell it "DON'T GO AHEAD IF CRITERIA #1 HAS BEEN FAILED". How can I stop this IBAction from carrying out if there is no text in any of the four fields? (My php file only checks for existing usernames and terminates if it finds a match in my database.)
2. When a user fills in all 4 fields appropriately, and presses the create button, im getting my "connection to server cannot be established" error which I have set. After having played around for maybe 3 hours with the code, i didnt get anywhere, in fact, i do remember a time where I was getting my profile create success alerts, but that was at a time where my database was ONLY recording blank entries.

Sorry about the wall of text, but ive been working on this for about 10 consecutive hours and not getting very far!!!

Any help would be much appreciated <3

```
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//create a user profile

-(IBAction)createprofile:(id)sender
{

    NSString* name = textFieldName.text;    
    NSString* username = textFieldUser.text;
    NSString* password = textFieldPassword.text;
    NSString* email = textFieldEmail.text;

    NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"name=%@&username=%@&password=%@&email=%@",name,username,password,email];


    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]; 

    NSString *serverOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:postData encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];  


    if(([textFieldName.text length]==0) || ([textFieldEmail.text length]==0) || ([textFieldPassword.text length]==0) || ([textFieldUser.text length]==0))

    {

        UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Missing Field"
                                                         message:@"Please fill out all fields."
                                                        delegate:self
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"  
                                               otherButtonTitles: nil];

        [alert show];

        [alert release];

    } else if ([serverOutput isEqualToString:@"Yes"]) 

    {

        UIAlertView *alertsuccess = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"Your profile has been created!"
                                                              delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

        [alertsuccess show];
        [alertsuccess release];

    } else if ([serverOutput isEqualToString:@"No"])

    {

        UIAlertView *alertsuccess = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"The specified username is already taken."
                                                              delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alertsuccess show];
        [alertsuccess release];

    } else {

        UIAlertView *alertsuccess = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Connection to server cannot be established."
                                                              delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alertsuccess show];
        [alertsuccess release];

    }




    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];  
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mywebsite.com/userlogin.php?"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];  
    [theRequest setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];  
    [theRequest setHTTPBody:postData];     
    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];





    if( theConnection )
    {
        webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    }
    else
    {
    }
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [webData setLength: 0];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{


    [webData appendData:data];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{

    [connection release];
    [webData release];
}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

    NSString *loginStatus = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [loginStatus release];



    [connection release];
    [webData release];
}
```

Comment: Try using ASIHttpRequest. This library simplifies this type of operation.

Answer (score 0):

Showing an alert is an asynchronous call (it does not wait till you click on a button to continue on to the next line of code)

You need to have a return after every [alert release], otherwise execution flow will continue to the bit sending the data.

Furthermore, your serverData you are checking in this same method! The code looks rather odd to me. Have you looked at the SDK samples to post data?
:

```
   //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//create a user profile

-(IBAction)createprofile:(id)sender
{

    NSString* name = textFieldName.text;    
    NSString* username = textFieldUser.text;
    NSString* password = textFieldPassword.text;
    NSString* email = textFieldEmail.text;

    NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"name=%@&username=%@&password=%@&email=%@",name,username,password,email];


    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]; 

    NSString *serverOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:postData encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];  


    if(([textFieldName.text length]==0) || ([textFieldEmail.text length]==0) || ([textFieldPassword.text length]==0) || ([textFieldUser.text length]==0))

    {

        UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Missing Field"
                                                         message:@"Please fill out all fields."
                                                        delegate:self
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"  
                                               otherButtonTitles: nil];

        [alert show];

        [alert release];
        return;

    } else if ([serverOutput isEqualToString:@"Yes"]) 

    {

        UIAlertView *alertsuccess = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"Your profile has been created!"
                                                              delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

        [alertsuccess show];
        [alertsuccess release];
        return;

    } else if ([serverOutput isEqualToString:@"No"])

    {

        UIAlertView *alertsuccess = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"The specified username is already taken."
                                                              delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alertsuccess show];
        [alertsuccess release];
        return;
    } else {

        UIAlertView *alertsuccess = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Connection to server cannot be established."
                                                              delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alertsuccess show];
        [alertsuccess release];
        return;
    }




    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];  
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mywebsite.com/userlogin.php?"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];  
    [theRequest setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];  
    [theRequest setHTTPBody:postData];     
    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];





    if( theConnection )
    {
        webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    }
    else
    {
    }
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [webData setLength: 0];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{


    [webData appendData:data];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{

    [connection release];
    [webData release];
}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

    NSString *loginStatus = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [loginStatus release];



    [connection release];
    [webData release];
}
```

Comment: Yeah... but all good, for those who have this problem in the future, I ended up using ASIHTTPRequest instead, works wonders. Thanks for your response though!